# PHP sum up value in foreach separate

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I am new to php and I faced some problem when I need sum up array in foreach.

I had array like this:

```
  $arrays = [
                [
                      'orderid' => "1",
                      'price' => "100"
                      'rate' => "1"
                ],
                [
                      'orderid' => "2",
                      'price' => "200"
                      'rate' => "5"
                ],

       ];
```

What I face when I using foreach, the **price * rate** will sum continuously but not sum up separately.

```
     $bonus = array();
     foreach($arrays as $data){
           $bonus = $data['originalPrice'] * $data['rate'];
       }
```

I also tried using `array_map()` but also cannot get my answer;

WHat I need about :

```
$array = [
[
   'total' => 100;
],
[
   'total' => 1000;
]


]
```

Any idea for help?

UPDATED: ALL THE ANSWER ARE CORRECTED, is the api data give me wrong info lol.

Comment: You could use array_push() function inserts one or more elements to the end of an array.

Comment: Just use `$bonus[] = ` instead of `$bonus = `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `price` so use that property and you need to push the value in the result array. Thus, you need to do:

```
<?php
$arrays=array(
 array(
    'orderid' => "1",
    'price' => "100",
    'rate' => "1"
  ),
  array(
    'orderid' => "2",
    'price' => "200",
    'rate' => "5"
  )
);
$bonus = array();
foreach($arrays as $data){
 array_push($bonus,$data['price'] * $data['rate']);
}
print_r($bonus);
?>
```

You can test this code at http://www.writephponline.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach($arrays as $data){
       $bonus[]['total'] = $data['price'] * $data['rate'];
   }
  print_r($bonus);
```

Comment: still the same it will continue add

Answer (score 0):

Foreach is fine, but you need to add to the bonus array rather than override with the result:

```
$bonus = array();
 foreach($arrays as $data){
       $bonus[] = array('total' => $data['originalPrice'] * $data['rate']);
   }
```

This is adding arrays to the `bonus` array.